# Java's SWT: GC will not draw simple rectangle on a canvas, but will draw it on an image

Tags: java, swt

I can't get the GC (graphic context) object to draw a simple rectangle on a canvas, and I can't figure out what am I missing...

Consider this simple code snippet:

```
public class MainWindow {

    private Display display;
    private Shell shell;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MainWindow mw=new MainWindow();
        mw.render();
    }

    public MainWindow() {

        display=Display.getDefault();
        shell=new Shell(display, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM);

        shell.setText("Graphic Test");
        shell.setSize(400,300);
        shell.setLocation(0, 0);

        GC gc=new GC(shell);
        gc.drawRectangle(50,50,45,45);
        gc.dispose();


    }

    public void render() {

        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {

            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }

        display.dispose();
    }

}
```

This will not draw anything:
[image]

And neither will this:

```
public class MainWindow {

    private Display display;
    private Shell shell;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MainWindow mw=new MainWindow();
        mw.render();
    }

    public MainWindow() {

        display=Display.getDefault();
        shell=new Shell(display, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM);

        shell.setText("Graphic Test");
        shell.setSize(400,300);
        shell.setLocation(0, 0);

        Canvas canvas=new Canvas(shell, SWT.NONE);
        canvas.setSize(shell.getSize().x, shell.getSize().y);

        GC gc=new GC(canvas);
        gc.drawRectangle(50,50,45,45);
        gc.dispose();


    }

    public void render() {

        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {

            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }

        display.dispose();
    }

}
```

[image]

But watch what happens when I set the canvas with a background image, and paint on the image:

```
public class MainWindow {

    private Display display;
    private Shell shell;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MainWindow mw=new MainWindow();
        mw.render();
    }

    public MainWindow() {

        display=Display.getDefault();
        shell=new Shell(display, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM);

        shell.setText("Graphic Test");
        shell.setSize(400,300);
        shell.setLocation(0, 0);

        Image background=new Image(display, "background.jpg");

        Canvas canvas=new Canvas(shell, SWT.NONE);
        canvas.setBackgroundImage(background);
        canvas.setSize(shell.getSize().x, shell.getSize().y);

        GC gc=new GC(background);
        gc.drawRectangle(50,50,45,45);
        gc.dispose();


    }

    public void render() {

        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {

            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }

        display.dispose();
    }

}
```

[image]

Suddenly, a miracle. It *does* draw the rectangle.
So, it has no problem drawing on the image, but drawing on shell/canvas will not produce anything...

What am I missing here? Shouldn't I be able to draw on anything Drawable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a timing issue (drawing on the `Canvas` or `Shell` during inital construction will be over-drawn during subsequent paint passes, wheras drawing on the `Image` persists your paint operations in its `ImageData`). For the `Canvas` (or the `Shell`), you are supposed to draw during its paint event like shown in the [tutorial](http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-graphics/SWT_graphics.html#Canvas). The `PaintEvent` brings its own `GC` which is the correct one to administer your drawing operations to:

```
final Canvas canvas=..;
canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() { 
    public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) { 
        e.gc.drawRectangle(50,50,45,45);
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! One question, though:  Where is this subsequent paint pass? The above code is not making any more paint passes from the moment the GC paints on it, till I open the shell...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but by experience I generally expect automatic redraws to occur on opening, restoring and resizing the corresponding shell, and probably also when parts of the UI have to be redrawn due to partial obstruction (edit: and when a composite is layouted). Automatic as in the event queue does it by itself. You might want to investigate callers of the redraw methods if it really haunts you.